# Capturing Standard Image - REST API possibility

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[Capturing Flex Image](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/captureImage) in API is available in softlayer but capturing a Standard Image is missing or I might have not discovered .

I have searched on most of the places over the internet but still can't confirm it as there is no proof that it doesn't exist .

It would be great if someone can confirm that is not possible through API or possible .

Answer (score 0):

### To capture a **Santard Image**

Standard Images can only be created from VSIs, the method you need to use for that:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createArchiveTransaction](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createArchiveTransaction)

Here a rest request example:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsiId/createArchiveTransaction
Method: Post
{  
   "parameters":[  
      "imageNameTest",
      [  
         {  
            "id":45905857
         }
      ],
      "test"
   ]
}
```

**Replace**: **$vsiId** (Virtual Server's identifier), **imageNameTest** (group name for the archive), **45905857** (Vsi's block devices to archive) and **test** (note)

To get block devices, you need to use:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBlockDevices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBlockDevices)

To get more information for image templates see:

- [Introduction to Image Templates](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-image-templates)